# Как реализовать слайдер со статическим блоком внутри

Tags: css3, html5, вёрстка

Здравствуйде. Верстаю лендинг из PSD макета. Макет создан под Bootstrap. Застрял на слайдере..
Вопрос в том как между слайдами установить статический блок "Featured work" который не будет прокручиватся вместе с слайдами а слайды при прокрутке должни проходить под ним или скозь него. Если кто то делал такую штуку поделитесь опытом плиз.

[image: PSD макет блока со слайдером]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Comment: [OWLcarousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/center.html) например

Comment: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ тоже может подойти а в целом в чём у вас сложность, распишите подробней :-)

Comment: Вопрос в том как между слайдами установить статический блок "Featured work" который не будет прокручиватся вместе с ними и в то же время будет обеспечивать отступ между между активным и предидущим слайдом.

Comment: Блок  "Featured work" на одном месте а слайды при прокрутке как бы обтекают его.